# Post-processing the DOM in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I want to add target="_blank" to an HTML fragment that went through the linky filter. That is, I need to post-process the DOM *after* the content was completely rendered.

See this jsFiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/ADukg/410/

I suspect it's something around the priority of the directives, but changing that hasn't helped so far.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the linky filter will add the 'a' tags after the directive is evaluated and element.find('a') won't find anything.

I think the best solution would be to write your own url filter which then calls the linky filter and don't use a directive.

**Update**

I created a jsfiddle for that as well:
http://jsfiddle.net/jomikr/ADukg/420/

Comment: What I actually did is this: I implemented a filter that replaces />a href/gi with '<a target="_blank" href' in the result of linky. Somewhat hacky with the regular expression on HTML, but by far the simplest approach.

Comment: Certainly works as well - and without the somewhat ugly thing to get a string out of a DOM Node. Just to clarify: Filters are always applied after directives. So changing the priority order here doesn't help.

Answer (score 4):

You can do this with a setTimeout like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/ADukg/411/). even if the time is 0, it will only run after the angular finish it processing.

Answer (score 1):

1. Open file `angular-sanitize.js`
2. Go to **line 525**
3. Change it to `writer.start('a', {href:url, target:'_blank'});`

Alert - linky will add target _blank to every link, now!

Comment: I don't think it's a good idea to change the source of libraries you depend on.

Answer (score 1):

Renan's answer works well, but won't work on links that have been added after pageload.

If you need to add _target blank to new links, try using a filter with a watch event:

**JS**

```
app.directive('targetBlank', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.$watch(attrs.targetBlank, function(){
                element.find('a').attr('target', '_blank');
            });
        }
    };
});
```

**HTML**

```
<div ng-bind-html="textModel | linky" target-blank="textModel"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

and what about just using a function in the controller.

I'm using this in the controller:

```
$scope.getTarget = function(isExternal) {
    return isExternal ? '_blank' : '';
}
```

and in the html:

```
<div ng-repeat="slide in slides" data-slider-id="{{$index}}">
    <a ng-hide="{{slide.link == ''}}" 
       href="{{slide.link}}" 
       target="{{getTarget(slide.isExternal)}}">
...
```